# RegExp - How to match all except the last one if it is followed by something?

Tags: regex, vscode-extensions

I have those string examples (starts with a specific string: (ex: `S` and then, it is snake case separated by `.` and sometimes followed by `()`):

`T.name.other_name.another_name`

`T.name.again_name.ect_name.last_name()`

I'm trying to use a RegExp to match all the snake case parts (without the `.`) but not the last one if it is followed by `()`.

So the matches should be:

`name` `other_name` `another_name`

`name` `again_name` `etc_name` (and not `last_name`).

But I cannot manage to find one.
How can I do that?

---

If the matches include the `.` that is fine too:

`name.other_name.another_name`

`name.again_name.ect_name` (but not `.last_name()`)

---

I tried this regexp:

```
T((\.([a-z]|\_)*)*)(\.([a_z]|\_)\(\))?
```

and wanted to extract the 2nd group match, but it always includes `last_name`.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Is the number of parts capped or can there be any amount of them?

Comment: I don't really know, this is to use with this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) so I can highlight some texts in VSCode

Comment: Alright, try `(?<=T(?:\\.[a-z_]+)*\\.)[a-z_]+\\b(?!\\(\\))` (it is already escaped properly, do not add backslashes).

Comment: `T(\.([a-z]|\_)+\b(?!\(\)))*(\.([a_z]|\_)+\(\))?` it is your regexp except \b that specify the word ended and (?!\(\)) that ensure pattren don't follow by ()

Comment: If the one above does not work, try another pattern, `"(?:\\G(?!\\A)|T)\\.\\K[a-z_]+\\b(?!\\(\\))"`. Demos are at https://regex101.com/r/u3RdTm/1 and https://regex101.com/r/u3RdTm/2.

Comment: You could try: [`(?:^T\.|\G(?!^).*?\.)\K[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*\b(?!\(\))`](https://regex101.com/r/thScAj/1)

Comment: I believe Visual Studio Code uses Node.js, so I suspect it uses the JavaScript engine.

Comment: Something simple [like this](https://regex101.com/r/7YZYDq/1) wouldn't suffice?

Comment: @Scratte VSCode uses 3 different regex flavors in different components, so it is not that clear. However, the link OP shared proves this is not Rust regex flavor. So, either JS or Onigmo/Oniguruma. One of my patterns above should work, but we cannot be 100% sure.

Comment: Ok, I installed the extension and found out the flavor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need to use in the *Highlight* Visual Studio Code extension settings:

```js
"(?<=\\bT(?:\\.[a-z_]+)*\\.)([a-z_]+)\\b(?!\\(\\))": { 
        "regexFlags": "g",
        "decorations":[ 
            { "color": "yellow" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Demo highlighting:

[image]

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u3RdTm/4).

*Notes*:

- `"regexFlags": "g"` is important, as by default the highlighting is *case insensitive*. If you need to make it case insensitive, add `i`.
- Make sure the regex escape sequences are formed with double backslashes.
- **There is at least one capturing group**: the decorations are applied to capturing groups, and you may define as many as there are groups.
- The regex flavor is JavaScript, so you can use infinite-length lookbehind patterns.

*Regex details*:

- `(?<=\bT(?:\.[a-z_]+)*\.)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a whole word `T` (`\b` is a word boundary) followed with zero or more occurrences of `.` and one or more lowercase ASCII letters or `_`s and then a `.` char
- `([a-z_]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more lowercase ASCII letters or `_` chars
- `\b` - a word boundary (used to make sure the lookahead that follows could only be executed once, to prevent backtracking into the captured word pattern
- `(?!\(\))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match of there is `()` text immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thank you so much for diving so deep into the question, and for explaining in such detail the answer

Answer (score 1):

If simplicity is what you need, then using a bare minimum of a single assertion
at the end might be all you need.

Overall though, the easiest is to make a single full match, then split the result
in capture group 1 on the periods.

```
T\.((?:[a-z_]*\.)*[a-z_]*)(?![a-z_]*\(\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/W89xxe/1

```
 T
 \. 
 (                             # (1 start)
    (?: [a-z_]* \. )*
    [a-z_]* 
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?! [a-z_]* \( \) )
```